# Computing limit based on upper and lower Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I have a question where it is asking me to compute the $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt{n})}{(n\sqrt{n})}$$ based on the integral of sqrt(n) from the interval of $[0,n]$. Based on my previous answer, I was able to use the upper Riemann sum since it overlaps with the question nicely such that the numerator is equaled with the upper Riemann sum, but for the lower riemann sum, it’s kinda awkward since it goes from $\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{n-1}$ so any ideas on how I should proceed? Thanks :)

Comment: Note that $$\sqrt{n-1}=\sqrt{n} -(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})=\sqrt{n} -\frac1{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, though do you mind explaining where the fraction came from in the second line please?

Comment: You're welcome.  Just rationalize the term $\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1}$.

Comment: Hey do you mind giving my method an approval? I tried to keep the original limit equation throughout. Sorry if it’s hard to comprehend. So the 2/3*nsqrt(n) = lim n-> infinity (sqrt(1)+sqrt(2)+...sqrt(n) - lim n->infinity 1/(sqrt(n)+sqrt(n-1)). From there I divided everything by nsqrt(n) and simplified it to 2/3 = original limit equation - lim n->infinity 1/(n^2+n(sqrt(n^2-n))). The latter limit would equal to zero, thereby giving 2/3 equals the original equation. Btw, is it the equal sign or < when comparing the lower Riemann sum to the limit? Eg 2/3<limit equation or 2/3 = limit. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\mathbf{Method}\mathbf{1}:$

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots +\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots +\sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} \right) =\int_0^1{\sqrt{x}\text{d}x}=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}\mid_{0}^{1}=\frac{2}{3}$

$\displaystyle\mathbf{Method}\mathbf{2}:$

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots +\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}-\sqrt{\left( n-1 \right) ^3}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}\left( \sqrt{n^3}+\sqrt{\left( n-1 \right) ^3} \right)}{3n^2-3n+1}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: This doesn't address the question regarding the lower Riemann sum.

Comment: @MarkViola stolz

Comment: Yes.  You might consider explaining this.